# Animate the textview according to textview

Tags: android, animation, transition

I have a vertical linear layout which have two textview, I have added textsize animation to first textview
So the problem is when the text view is larger and whenever new line is added in upper textview, the lower textview just moves down without animation. It just pops up from previous position and pops down in new position. How can I animate the second textview to be animated when first textview height changes??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:text="one two three four five"
        android:textSize="@dimen/TEXT_SIZE_18"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:text="six seven eight nine ten"
        android:textSize="@dimen/TEXT_SIZE_18"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I animated the one text view size with

```
final float startSize = 18; // Size in pixels
final float endSize = 24;
long animationDuration = 600; // Animation duration in ms

ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(startSize, endSize);
animator.setDuration(animationDuration);

animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        float animatedValue = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        if (one!=null){
            one.setTextSize(animatedValue);
        }
    }
});
```

I want the two textview to animate automatically

Comment: Add your code with question .

Comment: I have added code please help @ADM

Comment: I have added an answer its working at my end see if that works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to so that is to use `LayoutTransition`. wihich can be enabled on a `ViewGroup` by using `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` attribute.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:text="one two three four five"
            android:textSize="@dimen/TEXT_SIZE_18"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:text="six seven eight nine ten"
            android:textSize="@dimen/TEXT_SIZE_18"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you can enable the transition for changing state with `LayoutTransition.CHANGING`:-

```
  linearLayout.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)
    final float startSize = 20; // Size in pixels
    final float endSize = 60;
    long animationDuration = 10000; // Animation duration in ms
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(startSize, endSize);
    animator.setDuration(animationDuration);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            float animatedValue = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            if (one!=null){
                one.setTextSize(animatedValue);
            }
        }
    });
```